# Impala/SQL - Query that can utilise GROUP_CONCAT and COUNT > 1

Tags: sql, hadoop, count, impala, group-concat

I am looking for a work-around where I can utilise GROUP_CONCAT and COUNT; that is bringing back a certain category(in this case i_id where c_num is > 1). Please see below:

--

SELECT

A1.i_id,

group_concat(DISTINCT(cast( A1.c_num as STRING)))

group_concat(DISTINCT(cast(A1.type as STRING)))

FROM A1 ;

| i_id | c_num | type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | I |
| 1 | 10 | J |
| 2 | 15 | I |
| 2 | 16 | I |
| 3 | 3 | I |
| 4 | 4 | I |

I am looking to obtain the following output:

| i_id | c_num | type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1,10 | I,J |
| 2 | 15,16 | I |

But instead I am getting:

| i_id | c_num | type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1, 10 | I,J |
| 2 | 15, 16 | I |
| 3 | 3 | I |
| 4 | 4 | I |

Essentially, I am looking to bring back i_id where there is 2 counts of c_num or more. Appreciate your assistance or any suggested work arounds for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to want `i_id`s in the result set that have more than one row.  Just use `having`:

```
SELECT A1.i_id,
       group_concat(DISTINCT(cast( A1.c_num as STRING)))
       group_concat(DISTINCT(cast(A1.type as STRING)))
FROM A1 
GROUP BY A1.i_id
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

If you specifically want more than on `c_num` value, then use:

```
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT c_num) > 1
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your assistance Gordon!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a subquery to determine multiple instanances and join it with original table to use as filter.

```
select 
group_concat(DISTINCT(cast( A1.c_num as STRING)))
from 
A1
join 
(select a1.id as a1_id, count(*) from A1 group by  a1.id having count(*)>1) cnt_gt_1
ON A1.id =cnt_gt_1.a1_id
```

here the sub query `cnt_gt_1` will bring data where you have two or more rows - when you join to main table, you will get all rows with two or more rows.